# Why the Title and icons return to the top of View when i close the screen and open it again?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

```
<View
    style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: '64%',
    right: 0,

                }}
            >
    <BlurView blurType={'light'} blurAmount={30} style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ ...styles.close, top: 55 }} onPress={closeScan}>
                <ArrowBack fill={theme.icon.white} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
    </BlurView>
</View>
```

This a scan screen and I want to make blurView to all screen expect
the middle part of the screen, the above part I put title and backicon
in the middle of it and when I close the screen and open they are
shown in the top.

Comment: I tried to fix the code formatting, please check if everything looks alright. If there is some code behind please add this also to the question.